# Read a file in django and find string in file

Tags: django, file, templates, search

i am a new to django, and i'm trying to execute a django code in an html template, but it is showing the same error and i  dont know how to make it work. I am trying to read some files and find the one that contains the string. This is the code in the template:

```
{% if documents %}
    <ul>
{% for document in documents %}
    {% if 'TheString' in open('document.docfile.url').read() %}
            <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No documents available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The error is the following:

TemplateSyntaxError at /subir/

Could not parse the remainder: '('document.docfile.url').read()' from 'open('document.docfile.url').read()'

What could it be, or am i doing it wrong? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are trying to use Python code in the template, like your `open()` call.

Django templates don't work like that - you can only use a very limited set of syntax, and the syntax is not the same as Python.

Everything inside `{{ }}` and `{% %}` needs to be special Django template syntax, not Python code.

See the [Django Template language documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/) for the full details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use code like this in a template directly see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) for available template tags and filters. From what I can tell by the code you have posted in your view.py you'll need something like this:

```
docs=[]
for document in documents:
    if 'TheString' in open('/path/to/document').read():
        docs.append(document)
```

after passing docs to the template you could do this in the template:

```
{% for doc in docs %}
    <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
{% empty %}
    <p>No documents available.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd need to look at what you are passing from the view to be sure of this, but I'd gladly assist in further help with further information if this doesn't help.